# Parsing nested JSON and creating new keys with jq

Tags: jq

I have a JSON file that has hundreds of objects. Each object has 2 keys with nested object\arrays one for assignee and another for epics.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1111111111,
    "assignee": {
      "id": 1234,
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "email": "Doe@doe.com",   
    },
    "epics": [
      {
        "id": 111,
        "title": "Big Code Issues",
        "version": 16
      }
    ],
    "location": "Nerdville"
  }
]
```

from the current assignee key.  I want to create a two new keys assigneeId and assigneeName.  Where the assigneeName is the firstName and lastName combined.  The original nested assignee key can be discarded.

from the epics key I would like to create and epicsID key with a value of id from epics.  The rest of the keys in the nested key can be discarded.

I am very new to jq but i would like to create following output.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1111111111,
    "assigneeId": 1234,
    "assingeeName": "John Doe",
    "epicsid": 111,
    "location": "Nerdville"
  }
]
```

I can create and remove keys with JQ but I am have not been able to iterate the JSON file to grab values from with the nested keys and put into new keys. I have been getting errors based on different command I been running but the main one is "Cannot index array with string "epics"".

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fixing a very small technical problem with your JSON, the following produces the required result:

```
map( {id,
      assigneeId: .assignee.id,
      assigneeName: (.assignee | .firstName + " " + .lastName),
      epicsid: .epics[0].id,
      location } )
```

You might wish to modify this if the "epics" array has more than one item in it.